# how to unbrick android device via stock recovery

Tags: recovery-mode

I have intex aqua y2 pro .
I rooted it using king root and edited build prop and restart it after this my intex aqua y2 pro stuck on boot loop now it is not recognizing by pc neither in device manager
 I want unbrick it via stock recovery by apply update from sd card  i searched for ota update but 
i found ony  intex aqua v10  ota .